# Django - How to handle on the fly checkbox

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm quite new to django, and i'm pretty much stuck on this problem.

I'm creating a website who can handle lists of objects.
Every detailview of a single object display all the list available for the customer (every list created by him or the other people working in the same company), checked if the object is in this list, unchecked if not.

My problem is the following :
I want that when the user press the submit button, my DB to be updated.

- If there is no change on the box, nothing happen on the DB
- If there is a change, of course, the DB is updated.

  - But only on the items who's "state" as changed

Here's my template:

```
<form action="{% url 'forms:add-list' artpiece.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for foo in list %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="listform" value="{{ foo.id }}"
        {% if artpiece.pk in foo.art_inlist %} checked {% endif %}> {{ foo }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And my models :

```
class ArtList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    creator = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    art_ids = models.ManyToManyField(ArtPiece, related_name='artid')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def art_inlist(self):
        return self.art_ids.values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

Is something like looping into every list and checking for the ID is present is a good idea ? Seems for me like a lot of "work" if i've got a huge number of lists...

Thanks a lot in advance ! I'll edit everything who's not clear.

Comment: Do you have a form defined?

Comment: Well, if you speak about the action field  
  
    `action="{% url 'forms:add-list' artpiece.id %}"`

I've got a class that print things like `request.POST.getlist('listform')`. Just to try things.

Comment: You could have a hidden field where you store the names of all of the inputs that have changes which need to be saved and use jquery to update the value of the hidden input when necessary.